# How to delete an emoji from a string?

Tags: javascript, string, emoji

I need to manually delete an emoji from a string. The problem here is that emojis are presented by multiple unicode symbols, for example:

```
''.split('') // output ['\uD83D', '\uDD25']
```

I could check if the previous one is `\uD83D` and delete both, because it seems like every emoji starts with it, but then I found out that some emojis could contain multiple emojis:

```
'‍'.split('') //  ['\uD83E', '\uDDD1', '‍', '\uD83D', '\uDCBB']
```

Though the pattern here is clear, I wonder if there is a best practice for detecting them?

Comment: `[...'‍'].filter(y => y!=="").join("")` not sure if best

Answer (score 0):

You have to use replace method with your string to replace with empty ''.

For example :

```
yourString.replace(/([\u2700-\u27BF]|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDDFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2011-\u26FF])/g, '');
```

or

```
yourString.replace(/([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF])/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution based on Intrl.Segmenter(). For those who interested, here is an [article](https://cestoliv.com/blog/how-to-count-emojis-with-javascript/#3-a-second-algorithm-with-zero-width-joiner)

Comment: ...and what _is_ that solution? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731

Answer (score 0):

This methods works for me

```
const removeEmoji = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]+/g, '');
}
//Example
let text = "Hello , World ",
filteredText = removeEmoji(text);

console.log(filteredText); // output: Hello , World
```

But it will also remove other non-ascii characters.